# Using 'firefox location bar' search in other applications

Tags: firefox

I want to develop a plugin for '[deskbar](http://projects.gnome.org/deskbar-applet/)' which will search the history and bookmarks of firefox. The [location-bar](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Location+bar+autocomplete) search of firefox is ideal instead of me doing a simple sql query to the history and bookmarks database of firefox.

Is there a way I could obtain the results of a location-bar search through some programming interface which firefox provides so that I could use the same to develop the before said deskbar-plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can directly access places.sqlite database file in Firefox profile.